# Changing a file name in Total Commander without changing the extension

Tags: total-commander

When I left click on a file name in Total Commander, and the file is highlighted so it can be renamed, is there a way to exclude the file extension so only the file name is renamed?

Example: If this file name is the example trumpet.srt when I left click on it I only wish to highlight trumpet, that way if there is a subtitle file for a video, I can copy the video files name, and left click on the subtitle file that has a different name, and only rename what comes before .srt

Answer (score 4):

This option can be found at **Configuration → Operation → Main program → Select only the file name when renaming**.

The corresponding wincmd.ini setting is `RenameSelOnlyName=1`.